# Is the Cylon Test reliable?

Tags: battlestar-galactica, battlestar-galactica-2004

In the first season of the rebooted [*Battlestar Galactica*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0407362/?ref_=nv_sr_1) they mentioned that they wanted to perform Cylon tests on people in sensitive positions first, and that they are going to start with Commander Adama. Given that and that

> Tigh is revealed later to be a Cylon, why was he not discovered within the first week of testing?

Comment: Tigh is one of the "five".  They are very highly advanced (even more than the Boomer/Athena/8 model) and basically indistinguishable from humans.  Also, Baltar was the one performing those tests and he was lying through his teeth about their effectiveness.

Comment: @Tim Even as one of the 5, it is later commented that One killed the Five sometime after/during the first Cylon war, so wouldn't their bodies have the same imperfections as whatever the new models (1-8) have?

Comment: Also, we know the test works as it caught Boomer, but he lied so as not to have his neck broken by her...

Comment: Hmm, good point.  I suspect Baltar was the reason he wasn't detected.

Comment: @Tim True, and at the end of that same episode it is implied that Baltar lied about Ellen's test as well, so I guess the question should be why did Baltar lie about both Tigh's tests?

Comment: For that I don't have an answer. But anyone who's in a constant state of mental confusion due to an invisible sex bot probably isn't all that reliable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because after the initial positive test of Boomer (which Baltar hides to save his neck), and Baltar later discovering that each sample will take ~11 hours to test, he fixes the cylon detector to give everyone a pass.

> The functioning Cylon detector created by Baltar confirms that Sharon
>   Valerii is indeed a Cylon, a fact that Baltar hides from Valerii,
>   fearing what her Cylon persona would do were he to tell her (TRS:
>   "Flesh and Bone"). After discovering that it would be easier for him
>   to make all the results "green," Baltar alters the device to mimic
>   this method of thinking (TRS: "Tigh Me Up, Tigh Me Down"). However,
>   after Sharon Valerii shoots Commander Adama, everyone believes the
>   Cylon detector to be a failure, thinking that it did not pick up her
>   Cylon nature (TRS: "Resistance", "He That Believeth In Me").

[Source.](https://en.battlestarwikiclone.org/wiki/Cylon_detector)