# Why did Baltar not run to Adama after he successfully detects his first cylon?

Tags: battlestar-galactica, battlestar-galactica-2004

Baltar gets a positive result when

> Boomer forces him to test her

But he lies to the test subject in order to save his own skin (following advice from head-six)

However, what prevented him from taking the information to Adama as soon as the cylon was safely away from him?

Comment: He's a bloody coward.  If he had a working test, being the only one who'd be able to work it, he'd be a target.  I think he even mumbles it at the end of that ep to head-six - no positives, no problem.

Comment: Hmm... that might be the next episode (the "funny" one) where he says that... so that's after he's been hiding the revelation and he would have to explain why he delayed... if there'd never "been" a positive,  he doesn't have  too explain anything

Comment: Related, but not a dupe: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/169094/75476 (warning: question contains a major spoiler for later seasons).

Comment: If I remember correctly he was afraid of beeing a cylon himself. Head-six planted this fear into his mind. He not wanted to finish the detector to buy himself time. After all he is not interested in the survival of humanity, only his own survival.